# Drupal email file attachment on form submit

Tags: email, drupal, mime-mail

I have a form built into a block on one of my content types, the content type has a file connected to the node.

I currently have a form the will send an email to the address you put in with a default message (ie if you put into the form, me@myemail.com, this email will receive a message saying "thank you for your interest.. ..please find your document attached" etc) However I'm struggling when it comes to attaching the file attachment of that node to the form, I have downloaded the mimemail module but there isn't a lot of documentation on how to do it.

(I apologise for repeating this question from the Drupal specific SO but this area seems to get more traffic)

Comment: Is your form a custom form you constructed via Drupal api or is it a webform?

Comment: Its a form I have built using the Form API, its just a single entry box form for the users email

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would recommend you transition to webform rather than your own bespoke solution - as great and admirable as that is.

In looking around for a webform strategy to test and recommend, I found something that should do the job for you.

Have a look at [this](http://justinphelan.com/post/add-attachment-drupal-webform-confirmation-email) tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for finding this, the problem with this might be that I already have a webform on the node providing some other functionality.

Comment: OR - and this is me mostly thinking aloud - could I create a webform that requests the users email address, but create it as a block, then apply that block to this content type node with that functionality?

Comment: Absolutely, a block based webform was exactly what I envisioned. That should work just fine

Comment: Thanks for this, I've tried it this morning but I couldn't get it to work, I couldnt get it to pick up the information about the node the block was sitting on

Comment: Assuming the file is static and so never changes why not just provide the location to the file as described in the tutorial? You can also isolate the webform to that page only so it always emails the same file.

Comment: Unfortunately the file is dynamic, if they are on node A, I want them to receive the file attached to node A. It would only be for one content type and all the files would be saved in the private folder structure I have